# Exporting GeoTIFF error code:3

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working to export a GeoTIFF, but am running into this error:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. 
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3).
```

Here is my code. What may I be doing wrong here?

```
Map.setCenter(-75.517112, -12.72407, 13)

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA");

var l8_2020 = l8.filterDate('2019-03-21','2019-06-21');

var addSAVI = function(image){
  var SaviPerImage = image.expression(
    '(NIR-RED)*(1.5)/(NIR+RED+0.5)', {
      'NIR': image.select('B5'),
      'RED' : image.select('B4'),
    }).rename('SAVI')
return image.addBands(SaviPerImage);    
};

var imageWithSAVI = l8_2020.map(addSAVI);
print(imageWithSAVI.first());
Map.addLayer(imageWithSAVI.select('SAVI', 'B2','B3', 'B4'),{},'SAVI');

Map.setCenter(-75.517112, -12.72407, 13)

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA");

var l8_2020 = l8.filterDate('2019-03-21','2019-06-21');


var SAVIimage = l8_2020.map(addSAVI);
print(SAVIimage.first());
Map.addLayer(SAVIimage.select('SAVI'),{},'SAVI');

 Export.image.toDrive(
  {image: SAVIimage,
  description: 'SAVI2019',
  scale:30,
  });
 
 
 Export.image.toDrive(
  {image: imageWithSAVI,
  description: 'background',
  scale:30,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `SAVIimage` and `imageWithSAVI` are image collections (containing 42155 images each), while `Export.image.toDrive()` expects an image. To export, you have to reduce these collections into single images. How to best do that depends on your specific case. You can for instance get the median pixel value with this: `SAVIimage.median()`. You can read up [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_image_collection) and [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_reducing) if you need more information about reducing image collections to images.